# vertex-ai learn curve - batch predictions (label photos) without deployment to an endpoint?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

--resolved --  by using cli to UNDEPLOY the model then following docs
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/get-predictions#curl

to submit batch-prediction

vertex-ai newbie just trying to learn basics without alot of cost, using the vertex-ai dashboard to good effect ( training model and endpoint to recognize/ label photos using 3 categs from training labels)

but the problem i experience was that somehow , inadvertently thru the dashboard, the model was deployed and led to daily $30 charges to the project.

IMO - from the vertex-ai docs, you should be able to run batch-predictions WITHOUT having to deploy the model/ endpoint.

Is anyone able to verify the above?

with the current price lists, on a very small budget its possible to touch most of the bases ( create, train, test a model to label photos ) as long as you DO NOT deploy it. AND batch predicitions appear to be allowed with NO deployment. [image]
The only costly SKU i ran into was the actual deployment  see photo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> --resolved -- by using cli to UNDEPLOY the model then following docs https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/get-predictions#curl
> to submit batch-prediction

For the undeploy command details you can visit this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/endpoints/undeploy-model).

Sample command:

```
gcloud ai endpoints undeploy-model 123 --project=example --region=us-central1 --deployed-model-id=456
```